# Error creating RSS feed using CFFeed: value should be a String

Tags: coldfusion, rss

I'm trying to create an RSS feed from data in database using `cffeed` in ColdFusion. But when I try to run it, I get an error on line 24 (which is the cffeed line):

> **Detail:** value should be a String
>   **Message:** Exception while creating feed.

Here is the code:

```
<cfquery name="messages" datasource="showcase_Uk">
   select * from t_items where pid = 2 and spid = 45 ORDER BY uploadDate DESC
</cfquery>

<cfset myStruct = StructNew() />
<cfset mystruct.link = "http://showcase.com" />
<cfset myStruct.title = "Examples" />
<cfset mystruct.description = "Examples from UK Showcase" />
<cfset mystruct.pubDate = Now() />
<cfset mystruct.version = "rss_2.0" />
<cfset myStruct.item = ArrayNew(1) />

<cfloop query="messages">
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow] = StructNew() />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid = structNew() />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.isPermaLink="YES" />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.value = '#messages.id#' />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].pubDate = createDate(year(#messages.uploadDate#), month(#messages.uploadDate#), day(#messages.uploadDate#)) />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].title = xmlFormat(#messages.name#) />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].description = StructNew() />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].description.value = xmlFormat(#messages.description#)>
</cfloop>

<cffeed action="create" name="#myStruct#" overwrite="true" xmlVar="myXML">

<cfoutput>#myXML#</cfoutput>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What's the *exact* error, copied from the screen, including the line reference and which line of code it highlights? Update your question with this info.

Comment: Even if it doesn't solve your problem, try to get rid of those unnecessary `#`. They are only required within the `cffeed`- and the `cfoutput`.

Comment: Depending on the error message, it could also be helpful to see a dump of your query results. `<cfdump var="#messages#">`

Comment: Detail: <br> value should be a String
Message: Exception while creating feed.
Error on line 24 (which is the cffeed line)

Comment: @SamAllen Since I've tested your code locally -- with hardcoded data -- and did not receive this error, you could either try to generate a minimal working example with `QueryNew()` or provide us the data of the query `messages`. Additionally, you should tell us something about the type (Adobe or Railo/Lucee) and version number of your server.

Comment: Found the solution, the <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.value = '#messages.id#' /> was causing the error so replaced it with <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.value = xmlFormat(#messages.id#)> and it worked. Thanks for your help @Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following code at http://cflive.net/, where it works well under Adobe ColdFusion. Therefore I believe that the error lies within the query data.

```
<!--- Your query
<cfquery name="messages" datasource="showcase_Uk">
   select * from t_items where pid = 2 and spid = 45 ORDER BY uploadDate DESC
</cfquery>
--->

<!--- Building a new Query --->
<cfset messages = QueryNew("id,uploadDate,name,description")>
<cfset QueryAddRow(messages, 1)>

<cfset QuerySetCell(messages, "id", "123", 1)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(messages, "description", "a string", 1)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(messages, "name", "another string", 1)>
<cfset QuerySetCell(messages, "uploadDate", Now(), 1)>

<!--- From here on it is your code again --->
<cfset myStruct = StructNew() />
<cfset mystruct.link = "http://showcase.com" />
<cfset myStruct.title = "Examples" />
<cfset mystruct.description = "Examples from UK Showcase" />
<cfset mystruct.pubDate = Now() />
<cfset mystruct.version = "rss_2.0" />
<cfset myStruct.item = ArrayNew(1) />

<cfloop query="messages">
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow] = StructNew() />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid = structNew() />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.isPermaLink="YES" />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.value = '#messages.id#' />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].pubDate = createDate(year(#messages.uploadDate#), month(#messages.uploadDate#), day(#messages.uploadDate#)) />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].title = xmlFormat(#messages.name#) />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].description = StructNew() />
   <cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].description.value = xmlFormat(#messages.description#)>
</cfloop>

<cffeed action="create" name="#myStruct#" overwrite="true" xmlVar="myXML">

<!--- Show the complete xml --->
<cfoutput>#myXML#</cfoutput>
<br><br>
<cfoutput>#XMLFormat(myXML)#</cfoutput>
```